# MySQL customized exists query performance

Tags: mysql, sql, count, exists

Because of using Hibernate, I cannot write a JPA query using exists like this (I translated it to pure SQL query):

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM account WHERE activated = true)
```

So I have to write an alternative query to check existance of activated accounts. After reading several suggestions on this website, I see a replacement:

```
select case when count(*)> 0 then true else false end from account where activated = true
```

My question is: Is this bad for performance, is it short circuit query. Means whether the query stops executing if it finds at least one activated account? Or it has to get all activated account then at the final, check the total result if greater than zero or not?

Comment: Using `count(*)` to determine if any qualifying row *exists* is 100% bad for performance. You are asking the optimizer to count all rows, which it will do. Saying that, there are some optimizations that can be done to check for this kind of logic being implemented using a count, I don't know if MySql implements them, you'd need to check the *explain plan*

Comment: What version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: @SimonBrahan I use spring-data-jpa 2.3.4 which depends on hibernate 5.4.21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query seems reaching, why not just a simple

```
select count(*) 
   from account 
   where activated = true
```

Done, you get one record back with a count.  But if you are looking just to see if ANY account is activated, all you need is

```
select 1
   from account 
   where activated = true
   limit 1
```

Here, you are forcing a limit of 1, so as soon as the first qualifying is found, the query is done, and you can proceed -- even if your database has 1000's (or even millions) of records.

Answer (score 1):

(These comments are specific to MySQL with InnoDB.)

`EXISTS()` runs until it finds the first row that matches.  `COUNT()` must find all the matches.  So, `EXISTS` is at least as fast as `COUNT`, possibly a lot faster.

`EXISTS` returns `true` or `false`
`a > b` returns `true` or `false`
`COUNT(*)` returns `0` or more than `0`; see below
`a = true` has the same effect as `a`

My point is:  you don't need to do anything like `...then true else false...`

You may see `false` as `0`, non-zero for `true`.  That is, the `> 0` is also unnecessary (in your example).

To your specific question, the Optimizer is not smart enough to turn a `COUNT(*)>0` into `EXISTS`.

Comment: Irrelevant to MySql I know, but it's actually the case in SQL Server the exists and count(*)>0 produces identical plans, at least in version 2016+,